# how to use OR operator in nodejs

Tags: node.js, or-operator

I am trying to add an if condition; Idea is If I enter the input as print or text with 4 in it, else block should be called.

```
if ((turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('print') == -1) || (turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('4') == -1))
```

Now, it goes into the if block as opposed to else.

Comment: The `OR` operator will "short-circuit", this means if the 1st condition is truthy, the remaining comparisons are not performed: [Short-circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use: `&&`. Otherwise when the text is `print`, the text is not `4` entering the `if` block.

```
if ((turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('print') == -1) 
   && (turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('4') == -1)) {
   // not 4 nor print
} else {
   // print or 4
}
```

Comment: use `===` instead of `==` just to enhance

Comment: Enhance what? using `===` or `==` in this case, will never yield unexpected output. `.indexOf` always return an integer, and I'm comparing against `-1`, and just wanted to leave OP code with the only fix required.

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan Honestly there's no need to === because indexOf() always return integers which are compared to -1 which is an integer again, like Marcos said. Type comparison is also required if we are not sure about the return of a function, but doesn't hurt also even I prefer === comparison always.

Comment: I do prefer it in my code, but won't correct something that is not wrong due to my personal preference :)

Answer (score 0):

The execution goes into else block if text is 'print' or string contains 4 in it.

```
if (turnContext.activity.text !== 'print' && turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('4') === -1) {

}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is asking for. It appears as if they are wanting the `if` block to be executed if `turnContext.activity.text` is neither print nor contains `4`

Comment: @EvanBechtol Thanks I misunderstood and I have made the  change.

Comment: if I use this if ((turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('print') !== -1) || (turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('4') === -1)) ; string with 4 goes to else but print goes to if and it makes sense. With both set === -1. Both go to if block

Comment: @sunrise830 change it to `if ((turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('print') === -1) && (turnContext.activity.text.indexOf('4') === -1))` that means if input has print or 4, the index of 1 of them changes to a value > -1 , meaning the equality condition of one of them fails leading to else condition being called, because True and False is always False